# NA's produced when aggregating with dates

Tags: r

my data set looks like this

| id | binary1 | binary2 | date1 | date2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 0 | 1 | NA | 2021-1-9 |
| 111 | 1 | 0 | 2021-1-2 | NA |

and I would like to merge the two together to create

| id | binary1 | binary2 | date1 | date2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 1 | 1 | 2021-1-2 | 2021-1-9 |

I have tried this

```
aggregate(x=df[c("binary1","binary2","date1","date2")], by=list(name=df$id), FUN=max, na.rm = F)
```

but it produces NA's in my date columns when both binary1 and binary2 are equal to 1. Also I am running this on a dataset where some id's do not have either binary1 or binary2 equal to 1 so that's why I would like to keep the NAs in the date column when appropriate.

Comment: why did you use `na.rm = F`, it should be `na.rm = TRUE`

Comment: Ah yes I see my issue. The problem is I have NA's in the binary columns where there is no date associated. I need to mutate the NA's to 0s.

Comment: Suppose if you have NA in 'binary1 or 'binary2' and then if it is converted to 0 and there is corresponding 'date' value not NA. do you return those 'date' values or is it NA?

Comment: Perhaps `library(dplyr); library(stringr);df1 %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(across(date1:date2, ~ replace(.x, get(str_replace(cur_column(), "date", "binary")) != 1, NA_character_))) %>% summarise(across(binary1:date2, ~ if(all(is.na(.x))) NA_character_ else max(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))`

Comment: It may be better to create a better example that shows all the patterns along with the expected output. thanks